# Ionic Newbie how can i make list items bigger

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

For the last couple of days I have been trying to learn ionic because i have a school project and its so hard i dont even know where to begin .I had created an android app but my school kept on saying you gotta do it on ionic and as a "good" student i accepted.Are there any good guides? I cant seem to find any.
Also i want to create a list that has an icon on the left and some text on the middle.I want to make the icon and the text a little  bigger but i have no idea how.Here is the code:

```
<ion-list>

<ion-item>
    <ion-icon item-left name="moon"></ion-icon>
    <h3>Bedrooms</h3>

</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest you to go through documentation. And there are many tutorial video for latest ionic in youtube. That will help you alot.

and for your current font size issue, please try to edit either scss file for the given page but better update the sass variable in theme/variables.scss(please find a short tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1cgr0z9TXnQ)).

$item-md-font-size

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-grid>
       <ion-row>
         <ion-col col-2>
           <ion-icon item-left name="moon"></ion-icon>
         </ion-col>
         <ion-col col-8>
           <h3 ion-text text-center>Bedrooms</h3>
         </ion-col>
       <ion-row>
    <ion-grid>
  </ion-item>
<ion-list>
```

SCSS

```
ion-icon{
  font-size: 25px!important
}
h3{
  font-size: 30px!important
}
```

> Here is documentation
>
> https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-utilities/
>   https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/responsive-grid/